# ValidateAntiForgeryToken Doesn't Work with Axios POST in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, axios

Good day,

I have this code that uses RequestVerificationToken in sending a request to the web controller method. I'm using axios to send my specific request.

Here is my client side code:

```
var myToken = document.getElementById("token");
axios.post(`/Info/Delete?id=${this.id}`, {
    headers: {
        "RequestVerificationToken": myToken.value
    }
}).then(response => {
    alert(response.data);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And here's my web controller method that receives the request.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
     // something here
}
```

The console error that I get is: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`

But when I remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and the axios `headers:{"RequestVerificationToken": myToken.value}`, it's working properly.

Any help please?

Comment: how are you producing the token? Secondly have to used anything to show if the token is actually generated?

Comment: There's no problem with my token. Yes, it's generated using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery` its mechanism of ASP.NET Core to generate the token. It's working with my other modules so the token has no problem. Just to add up, in my Create, and Edit methods, I'm using the same procedure. It's just happen that it doesn't work with Delete and I don't know why

Comment: what is the route suppose to be for the delete method... default?

Comment: The `Delete` method is inside the `Info` Controller

Comment: yes I gathered that... but the routing in the startup.cs, is it `default` or something custom?  I too use the IAntiforgery interface

Comment: e.g. `/info/delete/5`

Comment: yeah, on my console, I'm getting the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172551/discussion-between-mvermef-and-jsongppd).